# How to open a popup window (a seperate view controller) via a function call in swift

Tags: swift, popup

New swift user here. I would like to open a pop up (controlled by a separate view controller) over the normal view controller as part of a function call (i.e. there is no button that is pressed or similar). How do I write this? I would also like to send information to that influences the images that are shown in the pop up.

I have previously managed to open a modal pop-up via a button press. I don't really know if there is something peculiar about these kinds of popups but if there are I'd like to have the pop up above look the same.

I hope this is clear enough for someone to understand what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method in super view controller like this:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - View methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    /// This Method is used for Alert With Action Method
    func showAlertViewWithPopAction(message: String, title: String) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
                ///add you logic here
         }
         alert.addAction(okAction)
         self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
}
```

And Inherit this controller in every controller like this and call this method from the controller like this:

```
 class FirstViewController: MainViewController {

        // MARK: - View methods
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        ///Call alert method according to your use
            Self.showAlertViewWithPopAction(message: "This is demo alert", title: "Alert")

        }
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to all of this. Where does this code go? Where does the name for the popup-view controller go? Among the other things I don't understand are "Action method", "Alert", "UIAlertController", "self.present". Sorry.

Comment: You can add this method in superviewcontroller and call this method from any controller which is inherit to superviewcontroller

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but there is too much I don't understand in the answer. In addition to the things I mentioned, I don't understand if the FirstViewController is the same as the MainViewController / SuperViewController, or if any of this code go in the view controller for the pop up?

Comment: MainViewController / SuperViewController is only for your common methods which is going to use in every controller. And all your controller inherit the MainViewController like (class secondViewController: MainViewController) So you no need to do any thing. You simple add MainViewController in your project and When you create a controller then change the inherited Controller name(UIViewController) to MainViewController.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is still too complicated for me. Anyone else?